# PHP: Failed to open required file that exists

Tags: php, zend-framework, require-once

I am trying to include the `Zend_Service_Amazon_S3` file by using

```
require_once 'Zend/Service/Amazon/S3.php';
```

I have also included in the include path the directory where the entire Zend library is located, AND the installation is inside Zend Server CE (which includes the Zend Framework by default). However, no matter what I try, I only get the following for my troubles:

> `Fatal error: require_once() [http://php.net/function.require]: Failed opening required 'Zend/Server/Amazon/S3.php' (include_path='/usr/local/zend/apache2/htdocs:/usr/local/zend/apache2/htdocs/app/:.:/usr/local/zend/share/ZendFramework/library:/usr/local/zend/share/pear:/usr/local/zend/apache2/htdocs/app/vendors') in /usr/local/zend/apache2/htdocs/app/models/item.php on line 3`

The Zend/Service/Amazon/S3.php is located under the paths:

- /usr/local/zend/share/ZendFramework/library
- /usr/local/zend/apache2/htdocs/app/vendors

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your error message says `Zend/Server/Amazon/S3.php` - Shouldn't it be Zend/**Service**/Amazon/S3.php?

Comment: My word! Such an amateur mistake, well as they say it helps to have a second pair of eyes sometimes.

Comment: *tips hat* My pleasure, I hate getting puzzled on things like this :)

Answer (score 0):

Could it be the process that is running PHP does not have the required rights to read the file? Don't forget that a directory needs to be executable in order for a process to change to that directory (i.e. see the contents of its subfolders.)

Comment: Even modifying the library files to nobody:nogroup with permissions 7777+X does not allow PHP to open the file

Comment: Did you change the permissions of the folders? What are the permissions on /usr/local/zend, /usr/local/zend/share, /usr/local/zend/share/ZendFramework, /usr/local/zend/share/ZendFramework/library, /usr/local/zend/share/ZendFramework/library/Zend, etc?

Comment: The permissions for all of the directories that you mention are 7777/drwsrwsrwt

Comment: Looks like the problem is something else. I'll let the answer here so others know it has been tried.